# How can I use a string to access a Perl array element?

Tags: perl

I have this Perl code:

```
@str = qw(a1 a2 a3);
my @array;
$s1 = 'a1';
$s2 = 'a2';
$s3 = 'a3';
```

Now given `s1`, `s2`, `s3` get references to `$array[0]`, `$array[1]`, `$array[2]` respectively. A switch case is possible. but how to get it in one or two statements.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you're going to achieve?

Comment: _Why_? You already have values 'a1', 'a2', 'a3' so why do you need the values of out the array?

Maybe is $s1 $s2 and $s3 corresponded to array indexes instead of values...

Consider perhaps using a hash... ?

Comment: `$s1` contains some string parsed from some input file. now i don't know what that string is, but it belongs to str. i need to update the corresponding string in the array. so search for the position in the array which needs to be updated.

Comment: **@iamrohitbanga :** By 'in the array' do you mean @str or @array?

Comment: @iamrohitbanga I think it is time for you take a break from posting and actually study Perl a little. I understand you are trying to get us to write what ever you need to write piece by piece and, of course, there is nothing wrong with that per SO's mission but your method will not help you learn anything.

Comment: @sinan i understand your point. i am working on a college project. and learning perl is not the only thing i have to do. but through these questions i see a lot of new things. i am comfortable with C like languages but haven't tried much of perl. but these questions helped me grasp concepts like hashes, grep, ref etc. quickly. that's the advantage of having a dynamic forum with so many active users. its like asking my neighbor about a particular syntax he is good at. sure i'll take some time practising the language.

Comment: @iarohitbanga: we understand that you're working on a college project and have other things to do. However, it's rude to expect us to do your work for you. We are also working and and have other things that we could do, but we are the sort who like to help. You are abusing our kindness though.

Comment: @brian sorry. i'll remember that the next time.

Comment: @iarohitbanga Isn't the purpose of doing a college project on Perl to learn Perl?

Comment: @sinan it is not specifically on perl. i needed to parse some html for some job at a much different level and i realized perl would be a good tool for the job.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you *really* want is a hash, not an array.

```
my %hash = (a1 => 'val 1', a2 => 'val 2', a3 => 'val 3');
my $s1 = 'a2'; # you want to read this from a file?
$hash{$s1} = 'new val 2';
```

Now, if you still want to use an array for the index names and a different array for its values, well, it's up to you, but **you are using the wrong tool for the job**.

```
use strict;
my @str = qw(a1 a2 a3);
my @array;

sub search_ref {
    my $s = shift;
    my $i = 0;
    foreach (@str) {
        if ($_ eq $s) {
            return \$array[$i];
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return undef;
}

my $ref = search_ref('a2');
$$ref = 'new val 2';
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear, but I think you're asking how to find the index of an element in an array.

You can do that by using `grep` over a list of the array indexes:

```
my ( $idx ) = grep { $str[$_] eq 'a1' } ( 0 .. $#str );
```

You can achieve the same thing with a slightly nicer syntax using the [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~vparseval/List-MoreUtils/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm) module.

```
use List::MoreUtils 'firstidx';
my $idx = firstidx { $_ eq 'a1' } @str;
```